# Non Ansi C++ example in Visual C++

Tags: c++, visual-c++, c++98

I am trying to find in Visual 2010 the syntax that are extension to ansi C++,
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/34h23df8.aspx

I see this:

> The C compiler supports single-line comments, which are introduced by using two forward slash (//) characters:

Isn't this suppose to be a standard feature?

Can someone give me an example of non-ansi C code which would pass in Visual C++ and failed in other compilers like GCC? I need an example to test out whether the \Za describe here http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/0k0w269d.aspx works.

Comment: Until recently the Visual C compiler have not been up to date with C standards, and didn't support the C99 which introduced single-line comments. Also note that there is a difference between C and C++, the two language share many syntactical forms due to C++ from the beginning starting out as "C with classes", but now are two completely different languages. Do not mix C and C++.

Comment: mixing C and C++ in a project is OK

Comment: @JoachimPileborg Thanks:) my main question is on the second part, I have updated my question. My main concern is on C++.

Comment: @MattMcNabb: Nope, it's dangerous due to different behavior of many statements that have same syntax!

Comment: What I meant with not mixing C and C++ is to not write C in C++. It's of course okay to have C source files compiled with a C compiler in a project that also have C++ source files compiled with a C++ compiler.

Comment: Before the 1999 ISO C standard, C did not support `//` comments (though some compilers supported them as an extension). The current standards for both C and C++ are published by ISO, not by ANSI; in fact there has never been an "ANSI C++" (except that ANSI officially adopts each ISO C++ standard). Are you asking for non-standard C code (as you say in the body of your question) or non-standard C++ code (as you say in the title)?

Comment: @MM don't use such statements in shared header files; only declarations

Comment: @KeithThompson yes, what I mean is non-standard C++ code

Answer (score 0):

Example from [their documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/34h23df8(v=vs.100).aspx):

```
extern int clip();
static int clip()
{}
```

This compiles only with language extensions enabled, in both C and C++.

Strangely enough, their documentation seems very much outdated. Many examples of non-conformant code which should compile when extensions enabled in fact don't compile in either mode.